# unity crashes after git reset with no hint on what is going on

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, jetbrains-rider

I am developing a game in unity for 4 months now. today I reset my local repo to a state from a few days ago. since then, unity claims there would be "compilation errors" and offers me to open the project in "safe mode" or ignore the errors and continue to load the project. whatever I choose, unity crashes.

What I tried:

1. Open the project by clicking "ignore" in the unity dialog. Unity suddenly starts modifying the using statements in my C# files. I have no clue as to why that is. Rider starts complaining about issues.
2. Reset git to the current state again. Rider says everything is fine.
3. Copy the whole folder to be able to do multiple repair attempts.
4. Download the current state from Azure DevOps, overwrite everything in the project. Unity is now able to open the project in safe mode and starts complaining about missing files in the `library` and `library / bee folder`. I found the missing files in other projects and 1 on a  random git repo online that seems to mirror official sources and keeps older version.
   While working through that I noticed unity started to complain about missing C# scripts. The scripts were there, but it was searching in an old location of the scripts. So I think something got reset to the old state and is stuck there :S
   I moved the files including the meta files to the old location and restarted unity. Now it complained about components in `library` and `library / bee` again, so I copied the files there and unity started crashing again.
5. create a new project, copy my files and the asset files in there. unity crashes

Unity crash:

```
Obtained 10 stack frames
0x00007ff700d33866 (Unity) AssetImportManager::Import
0x00007ff700d37b94 (Unity) ImportOutOfDateAssets
0x00007ff700d42f79 (Unity) RefreshInternalV2
0x00007ff700d4ab7f (Unity) StopAssetImportingV2Internal
0x00007ff700d384bd (Unity) InitialRefreshV2
0x00007ff70053d566 (Unity) Application::InitializeProject
0x00007ff7009d5495 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff701d9c9ae (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffbe0a326bd (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffbe0cadfb8 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

CrashLog: `https://pastebin.com/SurWU6QT`

The crash log states:
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image F:\prog\Unity\myProject\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.8.0\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Dependencies\YamlDotNet\Unity.VisualScripting.YamlDotNet.dll
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image F:\prog\Unity\myProject\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.8.0\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Dependencies\DotNetZip\Unity.VisualScripting.IonicZip.dll

I excluded the package cache from my git repo as I thought it's just a cache that can be rebuilt.. copying the files back seems to be an issue.
As soon as I remove the folder `Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.8.0` I can open the project in safe mode, but get these errors:  `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualScripting' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Package manager things it's installed, but uninstalling and reinstalling the package causes unity to crash with exactly the same error as stated in the crash logs above :/

After uninstalling visual scripting and removing all (unused) references to it in my code, unity crashes on start. I have the feeling that as soon as there are no errors, it crashes. In the crash logs, it still shows the `native crash` and `Got a UNKNOWN while executing native code.` together with the `Managed Stacktrace:` stuff.

I'm not a professional (game) developer and completely lost here, fearing for the loss of the unity project.

can somebody please help me figure out what is going on here? I've been battling this for hours without any progess.
Is unity stuck in the old state that I initially tried to restore?
I assume a big part of the issue is that in the meantime, I upgraded unity from 2022.1.f1 to the current version 2022.2.f1. Is unity confused because of the upgrade? how do I restore a working version?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: It sounds like you have somehow broken your local environment. A few things:

1. TAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR LOCAL ENVIRONMENT
2. Use the reflog to get back to where you left off before going backward in time

You can do a backup with something along the lines of the following on Windows: `robocopy .\source .\source-backup /MIR`. This will copy all the local repo state: the `.git` folder (preserving where you're at now), any packages/locals, etc. Once you've got a backup, you're free to do things like `git clean -fdx` to nuke all local state and deal with a "clean" env.

Comment: Another thing you can do is "locally fork" the code using something like: `git clone source-edit .\source`. This will make a local replica of the repo that contains all the info from the current workspace but allow you to edit (and push!) without disrupting the current workspace, which may be useful.

Comment: @PSGuy gives good advice. If the Library directory gets out of sync bad things happen. Since it should never be added to source control then anything that modifies assets like a reset can easily corrupt the state of the project versus what Unity thinks is the state of the project based on the Library directory. `git clean -fdx` *with Unity closed* should fix things at the cost of reimporting assets and potentially finding out something that should have been committed wasn't. So that's why you make a backup first.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja for bringing some tech-specific guidance.

OP, please note: while git is normally plenty powerful for preserving information, you're in the unfortunate situation where you need to preserve things that are held both in git and outside it. This is one of the rare situations where you need a backup because you had some working version before but the complete specification of that version doesn't exist in your git history (or, more accurately, you don't _know_ that it exists or how).

Comment: I usually keep two copies of the repo checked out on my machine. One to work in and one to clean and pull to make sure it'll work for anyone else cloning the repo in case I missed something or we did something wrong in the `.gitignore`.

Comment: @PSGuy and Retired Ninja wow thank you so much!!! ´git clean -fdx´ fixed it!!! I have to do lots of reimports as you said and have some issues with the render pipeline that I remember having when updating to URP but thats all fixable. Thank you so much!! If you'd like, please post the solution as an answer. This way, I can mark it as such

Comment: @RetiredNinja since I could not notify both of you in 1 comment, I'm notifying you this way :)

Comment: @PSGuy could you please clarify one more thing for me: Should the library folder be in source control, should certain parts of it be in source control or should it not be in source control at all? I am not sure I understand that sentence correctly. Thank you!!!

Comment: I have now found this gitignore: `https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore`
and followed this advice from the unity forums: 
If the files are already added to git, you need to manually tell git to forget them. Make sure to commit all you changes before running these:

`1. git rm -rf --cached . 2. git add . 3. git commit -m "git index reset"`

is that what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Be careful with this. In general I'd look for known file extensions and clean them up that way. Alternatively, if your repo is still young and doesn't have much history, I'd consider just re-initializing it with the proper `.gitignore` file. Cleaning/sanitizing history is possible but it's not the easiest thing to do (it's not complicated either, but can have high activation cost if you aren't super familiar with git and the lower-level commands). `git filter-branch` could help clean your history (instead of just `HEAD`). You'd want to do this on a backup and verify the build afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you like to post your solution as an answer so I can mark it as the solution? Otherwise I'd post it myself and close the question, but I'd like to ensure people see you were the one who helped me out here :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @RetiredNinja and @PSGuy, the solution is to:

- `git clean -fdx` with Unity closed
- Doing restore tests with another local repo regularly

Also, I updated my .gitignore with the content from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore